Api-platform/admin React-Admin Custom Request
I found a solution to my project to use api-platform/admin aka react-admin and show some data how I want. I also implemented the authentication (JWT), login page, etc. The frontend application loads resources and I don't have any problem with it. I also defined my httpClient and apiDocumentationParser and any request to API by the default data provider included the header with the bearer token.
const getHeaders = (): HeadersInit => {
  const userToken = token();
  return {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
  };
};

const httpClient = (url: URL, options: any = {}) => {
  return baseFetchHydra(url, {
    headers: getHeaders,
  });
};

const apiDocumentationParser = async (entrypointUrl: string) => {
//....
}

But I also created a custom endpoint in my backend (sf6 + api-platform) which I want to use in my frontend that I meant above. I've created a button component and on the onClick action, I want to send a request to this custom endpoint. Now I have a problem. I can create a request by fetch but I need to add the header with Bearer manually. I read about useDataProvider but it allows sending the default request or I need to define a new one (honestly, I don't know how)
const doSomething = async (id: string) => {
  const auth = localStorage.getItem("auth");
  const token = JSON.parse(auth ?? ``).token;

  const request = new Request(
    process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/this_custom_endpoint/{id}".replace("{id}", id),
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      }),
    }
  );

  return fetch(request).then(...).then(...).catch(...);
}

const DoSomethingButton = () => {
  const record = useRecordContext();

  return (
    <Button
      label="Do something"
      onClick={() => {
        const id = record.originId;

        doSomething(id);
      }}
    />
  );
};

The button is displayed in the list. I see this button and can click on it and then the request is sent fine. So in this form, it works, but I prefer to use the solution from react-admin and don't add this header manually. Is it possible?

The react-admin way to fetch a specific endpoint is to add a custom method to your dataProvider. Something like:
import simpleRestDataProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const baseDataProvider = simpleRestDataProvider('http://path.to.my.api/');

export const dataProvider = {
    ...baseDataProvider,
    banUser: (userId) => { // add a custom method
        return fetch(`/api/user/${userId}/ban`, { method: 'POST' })
            .then(response => response.json());
    },
}

Then, in your button:
import { useDataProvider } from 'react-admin';
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';

const BanUserButton = ({ userId }) => {
    const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
    const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation(
        () => dataProvider.banUser(userId) // use your custom method
    );
    return <Button label="Ban" onClick={() => mutate()} disabled={isLoading} />;
};

Thanks to that, you can automatically send credential to the API by implementing your own httpClient:
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};
const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:3000', httpClient);

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);

To build your dataProvider for <HydraAdmin>, I think you can use the dataProviderFactory which accepts an httpClient as parameter.
Hope this helps.

I installed ra-data-simple-rest but this lib needs a special format of data from api-platform, doesn't support application/ld+json, expects Content-Range header, etc.
